# Jquery on scroll decrease scale of div

Tags: jquery, animation, scale

I'm trying to create an animation like apple watch. https://www.apple.com/apple-watch-series-4/ on scroll full-width video section.

They are decreasing scale value from 1 to 0. i.e scale (1,1)

I've written below code. But the `scale` is moving from 0 to 1.

```
var docHeight = document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
    jQuery(window).scroll(function (event) {
        var scroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop() + 62;
        if(scroll >= jQuery('.image-text-effect').offset().top){

            console.log('docHeight'+docHeight);
            console.log('innerHeight'+window.innerHeight);
            console.log('scroll'+scroll);

            var scrolled = scroll / ( docHeight - window.innerHeight );

            transformValue = 'scale('+scrolled+', 1)';
            transformValue1 = 'scale(1, '+scrolled+')';

            document.getElementById('section-border-right').style.transform = transformValue;
            document.getElementById('section-border-left').style.transform = transformValue;
            document.getElementById('section-border-top').style.transform = transformValue1;
            document.getElementById('section-border-bottom').style.transform = transformValue1;
        }
    });
```

Can some one please help me to figure this out.

Here is HTML code for where i wants to change scale

```
<div class="section-borders-inside">
 <div class="section-border section-border-right" data-scale="x" id="section-border-right" style="transform: scale(0, 1);"></div>
 <div class="section-border section-border-left" data-scale="x" id="section-border-left" style="transform: scale(0, 1);"></div>
 <div class="section-border section-border-top" data-scale="top" id="section-border-top" style="transform: scale(1, 0);"></div>
 <div class="section-border section-border-bottom" data-scale="bottom" id="section-border-bottom" style="transform: scale(1, 0);"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to the Stack Overflow community! Can you please upload your HTML code so that other contributors can better understand the problem?

Comment: @MichaelHurley thanks for respond. I've added HTML code in question.

Comment: Sorry for being late, If you solved that problem back then please share your knowledge :D